# Put to Call Ratio in PineScript

Tags: pine-script

Can I know **"Put to Call Ratio"** in Pine Script? I read almost all of the help material provided by TradingView but so far, I'm not able to see any function.

Answer (score 0):

You're dependent for that on what feeds are available to you. This script shows an example using `security()` to fetch CBOE put/call info:

https://www.tradingview.com/script/mNNEuUQ3-Put-Call-Ratio-Buschi/

Comment: Yea but this is for the whole exchange whereas I'm looking for a particular ticker.

Comment: There's no Pine built-ins providing PCR for all instruments. The data has to come through a separate feed, so is limited by whatever is available to you feed-wise.